# Xamarin iOS ModernHttpClient Owin OAuth2 Bearer Token Authentication DefaultHeader causes "System.Net.WebException: cannot parse response"

Tags: ios, rest, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a Xamarin Forms proof of concept and have hit a bit of a wall with an issue posting to my rest service.  The rest service is a Web API 2 Rest service using OAuth Bearer Tokens. I have it running with a valid SSL certificate over https.

I can obtain a token just fine on the device, however, posting with the Bearer token Authorization header causes

> System.Net.WebException: cannot parse response.

If I omit the authorization header, the request fails at the server due to authentication.  If I include it, the request never goes out to the server (used charles proxy to verify).

The "rest client" is a simple wrapper around HttpClient with ModernHttpClient as a provider, defined in a PCL.  The "rest client" works beautiful from a console application.  I think I'm seeing an exception from a lower level in iOS related to authentication headers...

This is how I build the HttpClient in the PCL:

```
        Client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
        Client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
        Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://rest-dev.mysub.mydomain.com");

        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Authentication.AuthorizationToken); // Authentication is where I store the token
```

Then I post the model with:

```
        var strContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        var content = new StringContent(strContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync($"api/devices", content);
```

All of this is covered with a test application which uses the same PCL to post to the server.

Not sure it matters, but in case it does, within the Xamarin Forms PCL this is called within a new Command on login (after the token is obtained).

I have the same error whether I run in iOS simulator or on my device.

I found it interesting that when I don't use ModernHttpClient as a provider, I receive a different error when attempting to obtain a token:

> "System.Net.WebException: Error: SendFailure (Error writing headers)"

Research on that lead me down the path of setting up a valid SSL.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  My google-fu is at a wall.

**Update**

I think I'm on to the issue, it's related to the SSL certificate.  I used Charles Proxy and had it install its certificate to debug the connections and it just started working.  Still does not work without using Charles Proxy, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with IIS SSL handshaking.  My solution here:

https://serverfault.com/a/779895/42134

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue because my webserver is set to only use TLS1.2.  The SSL handshake worked after adding:

```
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

to the Startup.Auth.cs -> ConfigureAuth method in the WebAPI as well as in the initialization of the client code.